# I proved that $\sqrt{z}$ is a continuous function. My proof is not smart. Please show me a smarter proof.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, continuity

Let $U:=\{z \in \mathbb{C} - \{0\} | -\pi < \arg z < \pi\}$.
For $z \in U$, the equation $w^2=z$ has two solutions $w=\pm(u + i v)$, where $u>0$.
Let $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function such that $f(z):=u+iv$, where $u>0$.
We define $\sqrt{z}:=f(z)$.

> Prove that $\sqrt{z}$ is continuous.

Proof:
Let $z=x+iy\in U$ and $w^2 =(u+iy)^2= x+iy$ and $u>0$.
$u^2-v^2=x$ and $2uv=y$.

1. If $y=0$, then $x>0$.
   And $u=0$ or $v=0$.
   And $u^2-v^2=x>0$.
   So, $v=0$ and $u=\sqrt{x}$.
2. Suppose $y>0$.
   $v=\frac{y}{2u}$.
   $u^2-\frac{y^2}{4u^2}=x$.
   $4u^4-4xu^2-y^2=0$.
   $u^2=\frac{2x+\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2}}{4}=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}$.
   $u=\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$.
   $v^2=u^2-x=\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}$.
   $v=\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$.
3. Suppose $y<0$.
   $v=\frac{y}{2u}$.
   $u^2-\frac{y^2}{4u^2}=x$.
   $4u^4-4xu^2-y^2=0$.
   $u^2=\frac{2x+\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2}}{4}=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}$.
   $u=\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$.
   $v^2=u^2-x=\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}$.
   $v=-\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$.

So, for $z=x+iy \in U \cap \{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} | y\geq0\}$, $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}} i$.
So, for $z=x+iy \in U \cap \{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} | y<0\}$, $\sqrt{z} = \sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}} - \sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}} i$.
Obviously $(x, y) \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
So, $(x, y) \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ is continuous on $\{(x, y) | x+yi \in U\}$.

Obviously $(x, y) \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
So, $(x, y) \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ is continuous on $\{(x, y) | x+yi \in U\cap\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} | y>0\}\}$.

Obviously $(x, y) \mapsto -\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
So, $(x, y) \mapsto -\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ is continuous on $\{(x, y) | x+yi \in U\cap\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} | y<0\}\}$.

Let for $(x, y) \in U\cap\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} | y\geq 0\}$ $g(x, y) := \sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$.
Let for $(x, y) \in U\cap\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} | y< 0\}$ $g(x, y) := -\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$.

Obviously $(x, y) \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ and $(x, y) \mapsto -\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
So, $(x, y) \mapsto \sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ and $(x, y) \mapsto -\sqrt{\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}}$ are continuous on $\{(x, y) | x+yi \in U\cap\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} | y=0\}\}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}} = -\sqrt{\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2}} = 0$ for $(a, b) \in U\cap\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} | y=0\}$.
So, $(x, y) \mapsto g(x,y)$ is continuous on $\{(x, y) | x+yi \in U\cap\{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} | y=0\}\}$.

Comment: wow it must have taken you an hour to write all this

Comment: There are probably more *elegant* proofs than yours, but a correct proof is a correct proof no matter what it looks like.

Comment: Where do points on the negative ral axis get mapped to? They are in your stated domain but you have not specified  the value of $f$ for them as both square roots have real part 0. I think you want to remove them from the domain, because I'm not seeing how the function could be continuous if you include them.

Comment: @John Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @Potato44 Thank you very much. I edited $U$.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to note that if $z = x + iy = re^{i\theta}$ then $\sqrt{z} = 
r^{1 \over 2}\cos{\theta \over 2} + i r^{1 \over 2}\sin{\theta \over 2}$, where
$r^{1 \over 2} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta$ (suitably defined) are both continuous functions of $x$ and $y$. Here you can use branches of $\theta = \arctan({y \over x}), \theta = \arccos({x \over \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}})$, or 
$\theta = \arcsin({y \over \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}})$ depending on the region.

Thus the real and imaginary parts of $\sqrt{z}$ are expressible as products of compositions of continuous functions and as a result $\sqrt{z}$ is continuous

Comment: $-1+i = \sqrt{2} e^{i \frac{3 \pi}{4}}$. So $\arg(-1+i) = \frac{3 \pi}{4}$. But $\arctan(\frac{1}{-1}) = -\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: We must show $\arg(x+iy)$ is a continuous function of $x$ and $y$. And I think we must handle several cases separately to show  $\arg(x+iy)$ is a continuous function of $x$ and $y$

Comment: Then you can use $\arccos$ or $\arcsin$ depending on the region... see my edits.

Comment: Also, you might have to choose the correct branch of these functions to coincide with your definition of square root... but always there will be a branch that agrees with your definition.